# Programming- cryptography

Tags: programming, formatting

I have defined the following function in *Mathematica* to get a SET OF `m` SETS (these sets are the codes `{p,q,d,e,n}` for the encryption system `RSA`.):

```
RSA[m_] := 
  Table[ 
    Module[{prime, p, q, k, factors, d, e, n,ans}, 
           prime = RandomPrime[{2, 10^2}, 2]; p = prime[[1]]; q = prime[[2]];
           k = (p - 1)*(q - 1) + 1; factors = FactorInteger[k]; 
           d = RandomChoice[factors][[1]]; e = k/d; n = p*q; 
           ans = {p, q, d, e, n}; ans],
    {i, 1, m}];
```

The problem is that although it is not very probable, these sets can be repeated, and I would like to avoid this case, but I have no idea. I have tried using the *Mathematica* function `Union`, in which reapeted sets wouldn't be included, but I don't know how to add more in order to get just m elements (sets).

Comment: 'DeleteDuplicates' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a small modification of your code (aiming to achieve what you want).
Note:

- you have to deal with p=q (change to `RandomSample` of the small set of primes you use
- the case when k is prime, e.g. p=5,q=11->k=41. This leads to identity (encryption)...not very useful
- use `While` to achieve list of desired length

  ```
  rsamod[m_] :=
  Module[{set = {}, lg = 0, p, q, k, d, e},
  While[lg < m,
  {p, q} = RandomSample[Table[Prime[j], {j, 25}], 2];
  k = (p - 1) (q - 1) + 1;
  If[Not[PrimeQ@k],
  AppendTo[
   set, {p, q, d = RandomChoice[Rest@Most@Divisors[k]], k/d, p q}]];
  set = Union@set;
  lg = Length[set]];
  set]
  ```

Small testing that has desired properties:

```
enc[x_, key_] := Mod[x^key[[3]], key[[5]]];
dec[x_, key_] := Mod[x^key[[4]], key[[5]]];
testf[u_, tst_] := # -> {u, enc[u, #], dec[enc[u, #], #]} & /@ tst;
```

A small test:

```
testf[2, rsamod[5]]
```

yields:

```
{{5, 83, 7, 47, 415} -> {2, 128, 2}, {11, 31, 43, 7, 341} -> {2, 8, 
   2}, {19, 41, 103, 7, 779} -> {2, 459, 2}, {29, 59, 13, 125, 
   1711} -> {2, 1348, 2}, {97, 43, 37, 109, 4171} -> {2, 2963, 2}}
```

where {p,q,d,e,n}->{"plaintext","ciphertext","decoded using RSA key=plaintext"}.

I have tested on larger samples. Other answers may deal with efficiency or issues I have failed to consider.